# Need to add HDD to existing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 in one of my HardDisk with Windows 8 as Dual Boot.  Now i use Ubuntu as my Primary OS.  I found lack of space and purchased a new 3TB Internal HDD.  I don't know how to add that to my Linux OS.  Please Help.

I did the partition using GParted and created a 100GB Partition in ext4 file format.  In my Files, i need to mount always for viewing the contents of that disk.  Also, i am not able to create any folders or files as it shows that it is owned by root.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
PK

Comment: Are you able to mount the HDD?

Comment: Is that Hard disk(Dual boot-able, Ubuntu installed) is external?

Comment: Yes.  I am able to mount the HDD.  My Primary HDD is also Internal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the Disks utility to set it to mount automatically.

1. Open Disks from the Dash.
2. Select your disk in the left sidebar.
3. Select the partition you want to use.
4. Click on the gear icon under the partition and choose to Edit Mount Options.
5. Set the mount point and mount it on startup.

Comment: I am new to Linux.  Could you please help understanding HUD and how do i open the disk from HUD.  I did google and found this page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/HUD.  But was not very helpful.

Comment: I used the wrong term. It's the Dash. Click the Ubuntu logo on the Launcher and type "disk" then you'll see the application.

Comment: Thanks I did.  I have a /home mount already and wanted to add space to that with this new disk.  I also don't have sufficient space for installing applications.  What is the mount point i should give for that?  I gave /apps and saved it.  It asked me for a restart.  Upon restarting, it didn't allow me to start my Ubuntu.  I deleted the Partition again, as i was not aware of how to remove the mount point.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow. You don't have enough system space. That's a bad situation. You're either going to need to migrate stuff to the new drive or use UnionFS to join the new fs (rw) on top of the old old (ro). Look here for the syntax. See if it works before adding the drive to your permanent mounts in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.  I did just format my new disk and left the automount 'on'.  Found the UUID of that disk after mounting using "sudo blkid" and added an entry into my /etc/fstab after taking a backup.  It worked.  I moved my files into that new mount creating folder and created a link into my home folders.  Thanks a lot for your help.