# All my work disappeared from Ubuntu days after moving to a different drive

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, windows-10, format, delete

I asked a [question about gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008018/how-to-increase-home-partition-located-in-disk0-using-unallocated-partition-in) ten days ago. Everything worked and my home partition increased <

For the past ten days it worked perfectly with no issues; even switching back and forth between Ubuntu and Windows caused no issues.

However, just now I used the Windows partition and restarted to get to Ubuntu's. ALL new files and work added after migration had completely disappeared.

I am literally about to cry. What should I do? Is it possibly something I can restore?

These are my disks at the moment if it will help at all:

[image: Gparted screenshot]

[image: more partitions in Gparted]

**EDIT:**

OK after playing around I believe I am in my old home, this is proven by my browser history and other things. Now how do I get to my new home? And how to make it a "default" home?

Comment: It looks like you have 2 `/home` partitions; One in `/dev/sda5` and the second in `/dev/sdb2`. In these pictures the one in  `/dev/sdb2` is mounted. Is it possible your old data is in the `/home` in `/dev/sda5`? You should be able to mount `/dev/sda5` with a different mount point from inside Ubuntu to check if the data is there.

Comment: @user68186 thank you! Yes my old home is the one at sda5 and the new one is sdb2.Can you please explain mounting to me or guide me to a tutorial? I am a novice in this field

Comment: Here is a question that may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/266394/need-to-add-hdd-to-existing-ubuntu

Comment: You may want to write your own answer, describing in detail how you solved the problem and accept that as the correct answer, after the required wait period.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to add HDD to existing Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266394/need-to-add-hdd-to-existing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is that the home that was mounted was not the one I had been putting my work in. To solve this problem:

1. Open Gparted
2. Go to the partition where current work is (the unmounted one, no key symbol next to it)
3. Right-click partition and click <kbd>mount</kbd>
4. Restart